# Filtering a List using LINQ

Tags: linq

Hello I have a Class Called EmpowerCalendarCode:

It has the following fields CalendarCode, CalendarName, EffectiveStartDate, EmpowerTaxType, LongAgencyCode, TaxDepositFrequencyBaseTypeID.

I want to filter this list based on LongAgenyCode and EmpowerTaxType. So lets say:

```
public IList<EmpowerCalendarCode> GetEmpowerCalendarCodes(string longAgencyCode, string EmpowerTaxType)
{

     //todo:

}
```

If I get more than one EmpowerCalendarCode for  same longAgencyCode, EmpowerTaxType which has the same TaxDepositFrequencyBaseTypeID , then I should pick the one which has the most recent EffectiveStartDate. How ould be able to write a LINQ query. I am okay even if we have to do two three queries to get the result.

Any Ideas and suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ctx.EmpowerCalendarCodes
.Where(a=>a.LongAgencyCode == longAgencyCode && a.EmpowerTaxType == EmpowerTaxType)
.OrderByDescending(a=>a.EffectiveStartDate)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This will return, at most, a single result.

Answer (score 2):

```
return yourSource.Where(x => x.LongAgencyCode == longAgencyCode
                             && x.EmpowerTaxType == empowerTaxType)
                 .GroupBy(x => x.TaxDepositFrequencyBaseTypeID,
                               (k, g) => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.EffectiveStartDate)
                                          .First())
                 .ToList();
```